# Upload blob storage return issues trying to upload local container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azurite

I want to implement Azurite + Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

First of all, I Installed Azurite globally, and after that, I run `azurite run` command. Once I did with that I connect it via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer as a Local Storage Emulator and inside it, I created a container as image below:

[image]

Now I want to upload an image using the service in C#, so I installed ***Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.14.1*** library and try:

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        var result = _blobHelper.Save(files);
        if (result.Result != "Ok")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Test");
        }
    }
```

**Helper:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Save(IFormFileCollection files)
    {
        var isUploaded = false;

        try
        {
            if (files.Count == 0)
                return "No files received from the upload.";

            if (
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_azureStorageConfig.AccountKey)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_azureStorageConfig.AccountName)
            )
                return "sorry, can't retrieve your azure storage details from appsettings.js, make sure that you add azure storage details there";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_azureStorageConfig.ImageContainer))
                return "Please provide a name for your image container in the azure blob storage";

            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    await using var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream();

                    isUploaded = await UploadFileToStorage(
                        stream,
                        formFile.FileName,
                        _azureStorageConfig
                    );
                }
            }

            if (isUploaded)
            {
                return "Ok";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Look like the image couldnt upload to the storage";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return $"{ex.Message}";
        }
    }

  public static async Task<bool> UploadFileToStorage(
        Stream fileStream,
        string fileName,
        AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig
    )
    {
        // Create a URI to the blob
        var blobUri = new Uri(
            "http://"
                + _storageConfig.AccountName
                + ".blob.core.windows.net/"
                + _storageConfig.ImageContainer
                + "/"
                + fileName
        );

        // Create StorageSharedKeyCredentials object by reading
        // the values from the configuration (appsettings.json)
        var storageCredentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
            _storageConfig.AccountName,
            _storageConfig.AccountKey
        );

        // Create the blob client.
        var blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, storageCredentials);
       

        var fileBytes = ReadFully(fileStream);
        var data = new BinaryData(fileBytes);

        // Upload the file
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(data);

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

My credentials looks like:

[image]

The problem start when it tries to upload the blob in this line:

```
await blobClient.UploadAsync(data);
```

it returns to controller and show the following result:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:ee3c9ac1-301e-00ec-33fc-083eaf000000
> Time:2022-12-05T22:55:43.9223139Z Status: 403 (Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.) ErrorCode:
> AuthenticationFailed
>
> Additional Information: AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature
> found in the HTTP request
> '1uuge8Zz1qo2rnSAj7nCyN+IE6NgjmeBqa5CL4Wl9fM=' is not the same as any
> computed signature. The server used the following string to sign: 'PUT

What am I doing wrong or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
I updated the blob URI for:

```
  var blobUri = new Uri(
            "http://127.0.0.1:10000/"  //azurite blob service
                + _storageConfig.AccountName
                + _storageConfig.ImageContainer
                + "/"
                + fileName
        );
```

Apparently the issue above gone, but now it is throwing a new error

> The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.

It can be the binary data values?

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I added `+ ".blob.core.windows.net/"` to Uri as:

```
var blobUri = new Uri(
            "http://127.0.0.1:10000/"
                + _storageConfig.AccountName
                + ".blob.core.windows.net/"
                + _storageConfig.ImageContainer
                + "/"
                + fileName
        );
```

And now is throwing:

> Invalid storage account.
> RequestId:f42a80d9-9876-4c08-9c3a-32c93d112ffc
> Time:2022-12-06T02:13:09.876Z Status: 400 (Invalid storage account.)
> ErrorCode: InvalidOperation
>
> Content: 
>    `InvalidOperation`   Invalid storage
> account. RequestId:f42a80d9-9876-4c08-9c3a-32c93d112ffc
> Time:2022-12-06T02:13:09.876Z
>
> Headers: Server: Azurite-Blob/3.20.1 x-ms-error-code: InvalidOperation
> x-ms-request-id: f42a80d9-9876-4c08-9c3a-32c93d112ffc Date: Tue, 06
> Dec 2022 02:13:09 GMT Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: REDACTED
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/xml

**AppSettings.json:**

```
"AzureStorageConfig": {
    "AccountName": "devstoreaccount1",
    "AccountKey": "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==",
    "ImageContainer": "my-container",
    "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndPoints=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
  },
```

**UPDATE 3**

After the comments below, it returns the auth issue again

> Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly
> including the signature.
>
> Headers: Server: Azurite-Blob/3.20.1 x-ms-error-code:
> AuthorizationFailure x-ms-request-id:
> bbd5ed42-1b34-4a34-8bfe-4457a883a0e1 Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2022 14:07:57
> GMT Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: REDACTED Transfer-Encoding:
> chunked Content-Type: application/xml

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> UPDATE 2
>
> I added + ".blob.core.windows.net/" to Uri as:
>
> var blobUri = new Uri(
>           "http://127.0.0.1:10000/"
>               + _storageConfig.AccountName
>               + ".blob.core.windows.net/"
>               + _storageConfig.ImageContainer
>               + "/"
>               + fileName
>       );
> ```

The Blob URI format for Local Storage will be  `"http://127.0.0.1:10000/"+<Account_Name>+"/"+<Container_Name>+"/"+<File_Name>` but not as you have mentioned in update 2.

[image]

As per the code you have mentioned in Update 1, the correct format of the Blob URI would be `"http://127.0.0.1:10000/"+<Account_Name>+"/"+<Container_Name>+"/"+<File_Name>`. But I see you have mentioned it as `"http://127.0.0.1:10000/"+<Account_Name>+<Container_Name>+"/"+<File_Name>` and hence it is taking the file name to be Container Name which is resulting in `The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.` Make sure you update Blob URI part with below code.

```
var blobUri = new Uri(
            "http://127.0.0.1:10000/"  
                + _storageConfig.AccountName
                + "/"
                + _storageConfig.ImageContainer
                + "/"
                + fileName
        );
```

Comment: I did the changes and got the first error again: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.